# Multisite with unique domains not working with Forge config

Tags: cache, config, multi-site, server

I have a live install with a primary domain of https://marketing.vessul.co/ which works great.

When I've added another site to this install and it's location is another folder such as **/extra-site** it works just like it's supposed to.

I'm having trouble adding a new site with a unique URL. The domain is pointed at the server and clearly responds to changes in my Forge config file. I can't get Craft to "switch" sites to the new one at the URL. The closest I've gotten is recognizing the new Base URL when I specify it in forge.

My primary site uses basically this exact config for static page caching: https://nystudio107.com/blog/static-caching-with-craft-cms

The following is the current config for the domain which is https://marketing-test.vessul.co/

Note: I've tried the full config I use at https://marketing.vessul.co as seen on NYstudio107 but I'm not seeing any chance other than the Base URL being recognized.

Has anyone had luck with getting craft multisite to work with Forge?

Thanks,

```
fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/nginx-cache/vessulmarketingtest levels=1:2 keys_zone=VESSULMARKETINGTEST:100m inactive=1d;


# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/marketing-test.vessul.co/before/*;

server {
    # Listen for both IPv4 & IPv6 requests on port 443 with http2 enabled
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    # General virtual host settings
    server_name  marketing-test.vessul.co;
    root /home/forge/marketing.vessul.co/web;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    # Enable server-side includes as per: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html
    ssi on;

    # Disable limits on the maximum allowed size of the client request body
    client_max_body_size 0;

    # Ban certain bots from crawling the site
    if ($limit_bots = 1) {
        return 403;
    }

    # 404 error handler
    error_page 404 /index.php?$query_string;

     #Cache everything by default
     fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
       #add $abtest to do that (in fastcgi_cache_key)

    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
     set $no_cache 0;
     if ($request_method = POST)
     {
         set $no_cache 1;
     }
     if ($request_uri ~* "/(admin/|cpresources/)")
     {
         set $no_cache 1;
     }

    # 301 Redirect URLs with trailing /'s as per https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    
    # Change // -> / for all URLs, so it works for our php location block, too
    merge_slashes off;
    rewrite (.*)//+(.*) $1/$2 permanent;

    # Access and error logging
    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/marketing.vessul.co-error.log error;
    # If you want error logging to go to SYSLOG (for services like Papertrailapp.com), uncomment the following:
    #error_log syslog:server=unix:/dev/log,facility=local7,tag=nginx,severity=error;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/marketing-test.vessul.co/xxxxxx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/marketing-test.vessul.co/xxxxxx/server.key;

    # SSL/TLS configuration, with TLSv1.0 disabled because it is insecure; note that IE 8, 9 & 10 support
    # TLSv1.1, but it's not enabled by default clients using those browsers will not be able to connect
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    # ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5';
    ssl_buffer_size 4k;
    ssl_session_timeout 4h;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:40m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    # ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed.pem;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/marketing-test.vessul.co/server/*;

    # Load configuration files from nginx-partials
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-partials/*.conf;

    # Handle Do Not Track as per https://www.eff.org/dnt-policy
    location /.well-known/dnt-policy.txt {
        try_files /dnt-policy.txt /index.php?p=/dnt-policy.txt;
    }

    # For WordPress bots/users
    location ~ ^/(wp-login|wp-admin|wp-config|wp-content|wp-includes|(.*)\.exe) {
        return 301 https://wordpress.com/wp-login.php;
    }

    # Root directory location handler
    location / {
        try_files $uri/index.html $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # Localized sites, hat tip to Johannes -- https://gist.github.com/johanneslamers/f6d2bc0d7435dca130fc

    # If you are creating a localized site as per: https://craftcms.com/docs/localization-guide
    # the directives here will help you handle the locale redirection so that requests will
    # be routed through the appropriate index.php wherein you set the `CRAFT_LOCALE`

    # Enable this by un-commenting it, and changing the language codes as appropriate
    # Add a new location @XXrewrites and location /XX/ block for each language that
    # you need to support

    #location @enrewrites {
    #    rewrite ^/en/(.*)$ /en/index.php?p=$1? last;
    #}
    #
    #location /en/ {
    #    try_files $uri $uri/ @enrewrites;
    #}

    # Craft-specific location handlers to ensure AdminCP requests route through index.php
    # If you change your `cpTrigger`, change it here as well
    location ^~ /admin {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ^~ /cpresources {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # php-fpm configuration for non-cached content
     location @phpfpm_nocache {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # Change this to whatever version of php you are using
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_HOST marketing-test.vessul.co;

        # Don't allow browser caching of dynamically generated content
        add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0";
        if_modified_since off;
        expires off;
        etag off;

        # Use Dotenvy to generate the .env variables as per: https://github.com/nystudio107/dotenvy
        # and then uncomment this line to include them:
        # include /home/forge/dev.leslierotella/.env_nginx.txt

        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param    ENVIRONMENT             "production";
        fastcgi_param    SECURITY_KEY            "key";
        fastcgi_param    DB_DRIVER               "mysql";
        fastcgi_param    DB_SERVER               "localhost";
        fastcgi_param    DB_USER                 "user";
        fastcgi_param    DB_PASSWORD             "pass";
        fastcgi_param    DB_DATABASE             "vessulmarketing";
        fastcgi_param    DB_SCHEMA               "public";
        fastcgi_param    DB_TABLE_PREFIX         "prefix";
        fastcgi_param    DB_PORT                 "3306";
        fastcgi_param SITE_URL                   "https://marketing-test.vessul.co/";
        fastcgi_param BASE_URL                   "https://marketing-test.vessul.co/";
        fastcgi_param BASE_PATH                  "/home/forge/marketing.vessul.co/web/";

        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

        # No FastCGI Cache
        fastcgi_cache_bypass 1;
        fastcgi_no_cache 1;
    }

    # php-fpm configuration
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # Change this to whatever version of php you are using
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_HOST marketing.vessul.co;

        # Use Dotenvy to generate the .env variables as per: https://github.com/nystudio107/dotenvy
        # and then uncomment this line to include them:
        # include /home/forge/dev.leslierotella/.env_nginx.txt

        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param    ENVIRONMENT             "production";
        fastcgi_param    SECURITY_KEY            "key";
        fastcgi_param    DB_DRIVER               "mysql";
        fastcgi_param    DB_SERVER               "localhost";
        fastcgi_param    DB_USER                 "user";
        fastcgi_param    DB_PASSWORD             "pass";
        fastcgi_param    DB_DATABASE             "vessulmarketing";
        fastcgi_param    DB_SCHEMA               "public";
        fastcgi_param    DB_TABLE_PREFIX         "prefix";
        fastcgi_param    DB_PORT                 "3306";
        fastcgi_param SITE_URL                   "https://marketing-test.vessul.co/";
        fastcgi_param BASE_URL                   "https://marketing-test.vessul.co/";
        fastcgi_param BASE_PATH                  "/home/forge/marketing.vessul.co/web/";

        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

        # FastCGI Cache settings
         fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
         fastcgi_cache VESSULMARKETINGTEST;
         fastcgi_cache_valid 200 1d;
         fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
         fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
         fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;    
        }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/marketing-test.vessul.co/after/*;
```

Settings in craft showing both sites:
[image: craft settings]

Comment: Looks like ``fastcgi_param HTTP_HOST``, ``SITE_URL`` among others should be changed to the test site.

Comment: Unfortunatly not @RitterKnight - I updated those fields as well as the 'BASE_URL'  and all that is recognized now is the correct base url on this page https://marketing-test.vessul.co/test

Any other fields you think I should try?

Comment: When you go into Settings -> Sites, there should be 2 base URLs correct?

Comment: That is correct @RitterKnight - I'm outputting the site information via this page in the docs on that test page: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/sites.html#creating-a-site

It has the correct Base URL but not everything else is wrong

Comment: Can you repost your full config? ``nginx -T`` from the command line will show you a dump of it. FWIW  I'd probably comment out all the ``fastcgi_cache`` lines until you get the site developed or you'll go mad at why your changes aren't taking as well... I'm also not a fan of adding credentials or extra variables to your ``fastcgi_param`` params unless you have a very good reason to do so as it tends to make troubleshooting much harder.

Comment: Updated config @RitterKnight 

I can certainly turn things off if you think it'll help - my experience so far with the cahce is that using https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-fastcgicachebust works pretty well so it hasn't been an issue so far, even with a dev site.

Comment: Found this ``fastcgi_param HTTP_HOST marketing.vessul.co`` yet in your config?

Comment: @RitterKnight Yes so that's in two locations in the config. I just tried it with both marketing.vessul.co as both values and with marketing-test.vessul.co as both values. Neither made a difference even with a full cache clear each time